# Dynamic Language Translator pipe in angular2

Tags: angular, google-translate, translate

Currently in my project there is a need to translate words/text from one language to another language. I am using pipe translate of angular 2,  it will convert my text from one language to another depending on the language I choose, which is working fine.

But my question is, if it's possible to convert from one language to another with any kind of default pipe or something like this? Or even some kind of tool for such action ?

I don't want to hard code all the words first. Instead I want to change some dynamic content coming from backend/database.